# Title fetched from JSON data won't display inside card in Flutter mobile app

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web

I have trouble displaying data in a widget that is inside a card. Below is the code to display the  content inside the card via a widget. the code below is the widget that should display the project description and title on the dashboard page shown in the second image.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a8KOk.jpg)

```
  import 'dart:convert';
    
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import 'package:saas/models/dummy_model.dart';
    import 'package:saas/network_utils/api.dart';
    
    import 'progress_indicator_widget.dart';
    
    // ignore: must_be_immutable
    class ProjectWidget extends StatelessWidget {
      final List<Project> _projects = <Project>[];
    
      ProjectWidget({
        Key? key,
      }) : super(key: key);
    
      Future<List<Project>> _fetchProjects() async {
        var res = await Network().getData('users/project');
    
        var projects = <Project>[];
    
        if (res.statusCode == 200) {
          var body = json.decode(res.body);
          var tdata = body['data'];
          var projectsJson = tdata;
    
          for (var projectJson in projectsJson) {
            projects.add(Project.fromJson(projectJson));
          }
        }
        return projects;
      }
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        _fetchProjects().then((value) {
          _projects.addAll(value);
        });
    
        return Flexible(
            child: Column(children: [
          ListView.builder(
            shrinkWrap: true,
            itemCount: _projects.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return Card(
                  color: Colors.yellow,
                  child: Row(
                    children: [
                      Container(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10),
                          child: const Icon(Icons.list_alt, size: 12)),
                      Container(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 15),
                          child: Text(_projects[index].title,
                              style: const TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 16, color: Colors.black))),
                      Container(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 15),
                          child: const ProgressIndicatorWidget()),
                      Container(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 30),
                          child: IconButton(
                            icon:
                                const Icon(Icons.arrow_right, color: Colors.black),
                            onPressed: () {},
                          )),
                    ],
                  ));
            },
          )
        ]));
      }
    }


The code for the dashboard page in which I have put the widget is below: 

    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import 'package:flutter/painting.dart';
    import 'package:saas/models/user_model.dart';
    import 'package:saas/widgets/activities_widget.dart';
    import 'package:saas/widgets/project_widget.dart';
    
    class Dashboard extends StatefulWidget {
      const Dashboard({Key? key, User? user}) : super(key: key);
    
      @override
      _DashboardState createState() => _DashboardState();
    }
    
    class _DashboardState extends State<Dashboard> {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
            backgroundColor: Colors.white,
            body: SingleChildScrollView(
                child: Column(children: [
              Container(
                height: 40,
                width: double.infinity,
                color: Colors.transparent,
              ),
              SizedBox(
                  width: 390,
                  child: Card(
                    color: const Color.fromRGBO(0, 161, 39, 1),
                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15)),
                    elevation: 10,
                    child: Container(
                        color: const Color.fromRGBO(0, 161, 39, 1),
                        margin: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 30, top: 10),
                        child: Row(children: [
                          Column(
                            children: [
                              Container(
                                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: (15)),
                                  child: const Text('M & E System',
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                          color: Colors.white,
                                          fontSize: 18,
                                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)))
                            ],
                          ),
                          Expanded(
                            child: Container(
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 180),
                                margin: const EdgeInsets.all(6),
                                child: IconButton(
                                  icon: const Icon(Icons.settings,
                                      color: Colors.white),
                                  onPressed: () {},
                                )),
                          )
                        ])),
                  )),
              SizedBox(
                  width: 390,
                  child: Card(
                      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15)),
                      elevation: 10,
                      child: Column(children: [
                        Container(
                          margin: const EdgeInsets.all(5),
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 5),
                          child: TextButton(
                            child: const Text('My Projects',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    color: Colors.black,
                                    fontSize: 14,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                            onPressed: () {},
                          ),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(height: 150, child: ProjectWidget()),
                      ]))),
              SizedBox(
                  width: 390,
                  child: Card(
                      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15)),
                      elevation: 10,
                      child: Column(children: [
                        Container(
                          margin: const EdgeInsets.all(5),
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 5),
                          child: TextButton(
                            child: const Text('Current Activities',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    color: Colors.black,
                                    fontSize: 14,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                            onPressed: () {},
                          ),
                        ),
                        Container(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5),
                            height: 200,
                            child: ActivitiesWidget()),
                      ]))),
            ])));
      }
    }
    
    showAlertDialog(BuildContext context) {
      Widget logoutButton = TextButton(
          child: const Text('Log Out',
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
          onPressed: () => {});
    
      AlertDialog alert = AlertDialog(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
            side: const BorderSide(color: Color.fromRGBO(0, 161, 39, 1))),
        content: const Text('Logout successful!',
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
        actions: [
          logoutButton,
        ],
      );
    
      showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return alert;
        },
      );
    }

The function to fetch the data works as it is displaying the data in a list.
[enter image description here][2]

    body: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: _projects.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return Card(
                child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                  top: 32.0, bottom: 32.0, left: 16.0, right: 16.0),
              child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    RichText(
                        text: TextSpan(children: [
                      const TextSpan(
                          text: 'Project Name: ',
                          style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 14,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              color: Colors.black)),
                      TextSpan(
                          text: _projects[index].title,
                          style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.black))
                    ])),
                    RichText(
                        text: TextSpan(children: [
                      const TextSpan(
                          text: 'Project Location: ',
                          style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 14,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              color: Colors.black)),
                      TextSpan(
                          text: _projects[index].location,
                          style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.black))
                    ])),
                    RichText(
                        text: TextSpan(children: [
                      const TextSpan(
                          text: 'Project Description: ',
                          style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 14,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              color: Colors.black)),
                      TextSpan(
                          text: _projects[index].description,
                          style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.black))
                    ])),
                    RichText(
                        text: TextSpan(children: [
                      const TextSpan(
                          text: 'Project Completion Date: ',
                          style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 14,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              color: Colors.black)),
                      TextSpan(
                          text: _projects[index].endDate,
                          style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.black))
                    ])),
                  ]),
            ));
```

Any ideas on why it does not display the content inside the widget? So far there is no syntax error.

Comment: Have you print response of API ?

Comment: I have printed the response and it is fetching the data properly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is full code it's working properly

just copy and past it I have reversed named for running in my device ( project class to => setting screen and dash screen have project code)

[image]
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

```
// ignore: must_be_immutable
class SettingScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  final List _projects = [];

  SettingScreen({
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  // Future<List> _fetchProjects() async {
  //   var res = await Network().getData('users/project');
  //
  //   var projects = <Project>[];
  //
  //   if (res.statusCode == 200) {
  //     var body = json.decode(res.body);
  //     var tdata = body['data'];
  //     var projectsJson = tdata;
  //
  //     for (var projectJson in projectsJson) {
  //       projects.add(Project.fromJson(projectJson));
  //     }
  //   }
  //   return projects;
  // }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Column(children: [
          Container(
            height: 40,
            width: double.infinity,
            color: Colors.transparent,
          ),
          SizedBox(
              width: 390,
              child: Card(
                color: const Color.fromRGBO(0, 161, 39, 1),
                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15)),
                elevation: 10,
                child: Container(
                    color: const Color.fromRGBO(0, 161, 39, 1),
                    margin: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 30, top: 10),
                    child: Row(children: [
                      Column(
                        children: [
                          Container(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: (15)),
                              child: const Text('M & E System',
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      color: Colors.white,
                                      fontSize: 18,
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)))
                        ],
                      ),
                      Expanded(
                        child: Container(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 180),
                            margin: const EdgeInsets.all(6),
                            child: IconButton(
                              icon: const Icon(Icons.settings, color: Colors.white),
                              onPressed: () {},
                            )),
                      )
                    ])),
              )),
          SizedBox(
              width: 390,
              child: Card(
                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15)),
                  elevation: 10,
                  child: Column(children: [
                    Container(
                      margin: const EdgeInsets.all(5),
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 5),
                      child: TextButton(
                        child: const Text('My Projects',
                            style: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.black, fontSize: 14, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                        onPressed: () {},
                      ),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(height: 250, child: Dashboard()),
                  ]))),
          SizedBox(
              width: 390,
              child: Card(
                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15)),
                  elevation: 10,
                  child: Column(children: [
                    Container(
                      margin: const EdgeInsets.all(5),
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 5),
                      child: TextButton(
                        child: const Text('Current Activities',
                            style: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.black, fontSize: 14, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                        onPressed: () {},
                      ),
                    ),
                    Container(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5),
                        height: 200,
                        child: Text("Activity widet()")),
                    // child: ActivitiesWidget()),
                  ]))),
        ])));
  }
}

showAlertDialog(BuildContext context) {
  Widget logoutButton = TextButton(
      child:
          const Text('Log Out', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
      onPressed: () => {});

  AlertDialog alert = AlertDialog(
    backgroundColor: Colors.white,
    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
        side: const BorderSide(color: Color.fromRGBO(0, 161, 39, 1))),
    content: const Text('Logout successful!',
        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
    actions: [
      logoutButton,
    ],
  );

  showDialog(
    context: context,
    builder: (BuildContext context) {
      return alert;
    },
  );
}

class Dashboard extends StatefulWidget {
  const Dashboard({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _DashboardState createState() => _DashboardState();
}

class _DashboardState extends State<Dashboard> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // _fetchProjects().then((value) {
    //   _projects.addAll(value);
    // });

    return SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Column(children: [
        ListView.builder(
          physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
          shrinkWrap: true,
          itemCount: 12,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return Card(
                color: Colors.yellow,
                child: Row(
                  children: [
                    Container(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10),
                        child: const Icon(Icons.list_alt, size: 12)),
                    Container(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 15),
                        child: Text("_projects[index].title",
                            style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 16, color: Colors.black))),
                    Container(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 15),
                      child: Text("Loader"),
                    ),
                    Container(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 30),
                        child: IconButton(
                          icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_right, color: Colors.black),
                          onPressed: () {},
                        )),
                  ],
                ));
          },
        )
      ]),
    );
  }
}
```

it's scrolling perfectly :
steps1 : removed flexible
2: wrap with single child scroll view
3: give physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(), to listview builder

done.....!

Comment: checkout this one if found error then let me know as soon as possible

Comment: The changes have worked for me

Comment: yup....
happy to help you.. make this answer up